# Keyboard layout wingpanel icon is missing

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel, keyboard-layout

On a fresh 5.1 installation I don't see input method indicator on a wingpanel. Aside of it everything is working – `ibus-daemon` is added to the startup applications, I can change the layout with the hotkeys, but anyway, I'd have a place to see what's the current layout.

`wingpanel-indicator-keyboard` is installed, `ibus-daemon` is operating. So any suggestions on how to get the layout icon on wingpanel?

Answer (score 1):

Some guy on elementary subreddit helped me. There is a bug discussed on github: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-keyboard/issues/80

As suggested, I've changed `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` from `[('ibus', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru')]` to `[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru')]` with the `dconf-editor` GUI tool, and the indicator is visible now.

Comment: the path is org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.sources at the moment